# FxCop for .NET 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, .net-4.0, fxcop

I know Visual Studio 2010 has a [new Code Analysis tool built in](http://blogs.msdn.com/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/22/what-s-new-in-code-analysis-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx), but that is only for the premium and ultimate editions.  From what I can see the [latest FxCop supports .NET 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=9aeaa970-f281-4fb0-aba1-d59d7ed09772).  Searching I wasn't able to find any references to an FxCop for .NET 4.0.  Is there plans to continue to offer FxCop and for it to support .NET 4.0?  Where would I find more information about it and download it?

Comment: According to MS; professional developers don't need Code Analysis...
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The latest version of FXCop (v10) is bundled with the install of the latest Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .Net 4, released on 5/19/2010. From Microsoft - [Full ISOs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=35aeda01-421d-4ba5-b44b-543dc8c33a20&displaylang=en)

Once the SDK is installed you can find the FXCop installer EXE under %programfiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\FXCop (This assumes you kept the default install directory when installing the SDK).

Enjoy.

Comment: Which options did you have to install to get it? It seems the x64 version doesn't install it at all..?

Answer (score 6):

FxCop is now enhanced to work with .NET 4.0. You can find it here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/07/26/fxcop-10-0-is-available.aspx

New version is marked with 10.0 just like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I googled for FXcop 4.0 and found the following a helpful links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstscode/thread/74b2815a-626d-4aef-a08a-14c2fa72b506

Looks like its not yet out but FXCop support for .NET 4.0 is planned.

Comment: It has traditionally lagged behind with previous Framework releases, as well.  What will be interesting to see is how much of a lag there is with 4.0, because the entire Code Analysis engine has been rewritten from the ground up according to their blog. http://blogs.msdn.com/codeanalysis/archive/2010/04/14/data-flow-analysis-rules-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: I had read both of those links.  Should have included them in my question.  The forum post was in January for Beta 2.  I was hoping for something newer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to FxCop rules would be to use the tool NDepend. This tool that lets write **Code Rules over C# LINQ Queries** [what we call CQLinq](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL), supports .NET v4 and v4.5, and is integrated in VS 2012, 2010, 2008. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

More than [200 code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default. Customizing existing rules or creating your own rules is straightforward thanks to the C# LINQ syntax.

Rules can be verified [live in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx) and at Build Process time, in a [generated HTML+javascript report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule).