# .NET exception not caught

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, exception

I have a function that looks like this:

```
try
{
     _dbManager.InsertSearch(some data);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //do logging
}
```

`_dbManager` uses LINQ to insert data to a SQL database. Yesterday, the machine that hosts the database ran out of hard disk space and my program crashed. I got a crash dump which shows that there was a `SqlClient.SqlException` raised with an exception message reading something like "Database transaction log is full...".

**My question is:** Why didn't the exception get caught in the catch block above? The weird thing is, when I tried to reproduce the issue, I could get the same exception, but it was caught by the catch block. What could be the issue?

**Second, related question:** Imagine if we use a third party library and we don't want any exception thrown. We can use try-catch block, but this only works on calling thread. What if the third party starts new thread and an exception is thrown there? Is there a way to handle this? I know I can register our `UnhandledExceptionHandler`, but that seems to be a different from what I wanted.

Comment: Was the logging in the catch statemnt being logged to the server that had run out of disk space, by any chance?  Do you have a backup method of logging an error within the logging mechanism?  For example, our general practice is to use a nested structure to try to log first to our global error handling database, then to the event log, then to an email.

Comment: the logging part wasn't reached at all when crash occurred. it crashed inside _dbManager.InsertSearch(). btw, we do use MSEL logging application block, and configured it to log using different method.

Comment: and none of the method will log to that sql server machine

Comment: Kinda pointless to not post the stack trace you've got.  If you don't then spend your effort on implementing AppDomain.UnhandledException.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is: Why didn't the exception get caught in the catch block above?

As [David Stratton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60682/david-stratton) suggests, the system might have been out of disk space and not able to write to log file. There is also a chance that the process was terminated due to [Corrupted State Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx) that will not be delivered to your catch-all block in .NET 4. The exception that terminated process might have also been thrown from the thread that did not have catch-all.

> Second, related question: Imagine if we use a third party library and
>   we don't want [any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2349399#2349399) exception thrown.

I think that you will have to stop right there and rethink it. What you saying is that you are absolutely 100% sure that nothing ever can go wrong in the thirdparty library. There are certain exceptions (like `OutOfMemoryException`) that you should not be catching because your code simply does not know how to recover from them. The rule of thumb with exception handling is that you should **only catch the exceptions that you fully understand and know how to recover from**. Please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152354/which-exceptions-shouldnt-i-catch/7152374#7152374) and the links in it.

> What if the third party starts new thread and an exception is thrown
>   there? Is there a way to handle this?

The best way to handle this is to rely on default CLR policy that will terminate your application. The only reasonable thing you can do is **try** to log it by subscribing to [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx).

Comment: first of all, thanks for your answer. very nice article about SEH. so if a corrupted state exception raised, will that be shown in call stack of crash dump? because i only saw the SqlException in crash dump.

Comment: also, none of the logging methods i used would log to that SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is another `try/catch` block inside that `InsertSearch` method, which has conditional `throw` statement.

The implementer of the 'DBManager' class, chose not to `throw` in case there is not enough space to write on the disk. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Code contracts runtime checking I advice you to check compiled version of your DLL. 
Read this for details [Why .net exception is not caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866307/why-net-exception-is-not-caught/10866308#10866308)